# How can I construct this server backend route?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm working on a fullstack project where I need a way to effectuate the following scenario:

Upon a user submit event:

1. A request is posted to the backend
2. When the server receives the req., it begins executing some function
3. The backend should run said function on a loop/indefinitely until the backend receives a subsequent request which instructs the server to cease executing the function after the function completes its current iteration.

I know there must be a way to work this out, but I haven't been able to figure out how to condense my problem/question into something I can google search my way through.

The following will hopefully help to convey what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
let run_function = false;

app.post('/start', (req, res) => {
  run_function = true;
  while (run_function)
    the_function(req.body);
}

app.get('/stop', (req, res) => {
  run_function = false;
}
```

Comment: How should the response be handled? Should it respond immediately and let the loop happen in the background?

Comment: @Phil Yes, I believe it should respond immediately, and have the function looping in the background until the stop route is called. The answer you posted looks promising so far. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a job for [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) / [clearInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearInterval)

```js
let handle

// Default 200ms interval
const startLoop = (body, interval = 200) => {
  clearInterval(handle) // stop any previous loops
  handle = setInterval(the_function, interval, body)
}

app.post("/start", (req, res) => {
  startLoop(req.body)
  res.send("Started")
})

app.post("/stop", (req, res) => {
  clearInterval(handle)
  res.send("Stopped")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let LoopInterval = null;
    
app.post('/start', (req, res) => {
    LoopInterval = setInterval(() => {
        the_function(req.body);
    }, 0);
});
    
app.get('/stop', (req, res) => {
    clearInterval(LoopInterval)
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.